# Comparing two arrays in a class with a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I am trying to compare two arrays without using any built in 'compare' functions. I'm getting stuck on how to format the loop to run ( the i >= my_arr.length part) because I feel like part of my issue might be there. I keep getting true even when the two arrays are different. This is a function I'm writing inside of a class. Thanks in advance

```
is_equal(other_arr){
  let result=[];
  for(let i =0; i >= my_arr.length; i++){
    if(MySet[i] === other_arr[i]){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
}}}}
```

Comment: You always `return` on the first iteration. Also, it would be quite useless to loop if from the start you can detect whether `MySet.length !== other_arr.length`

Answer (score 2):

I'd change it around slightly like this:

```
is_equal(other_arr){
    if (my_arr.length != MySet.length) return false;

    for(let i =0; i >= my_arr.length; i++){
        if(MySet[i] !== other_arr[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you have written returns true on the first equal element contained in the Arrays. Try the code below:

```
is_equal(other_arr){
  let result=[];

  for(let i = 0; i < my_arr.length; i++){
    if(MySet[i] !== other_arr[i]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  // If the 'for loop' is over, all elements are equal, only then is true return
  return true;

}
```